# Concatenate Multiples CSV files in one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new in python. Here is what I'd like to do. I got a folder with multiple csv files (`2018.csv`, `2017.csv`, `2016.csv`,... etc.), 500 CSV files to be precise. Each CSV file contains header "`date`", "`Code`", "`Cur`", "`Price`" etc. I'd like to concatenate all 500 CSV files in one datafame. Here is my code for one csv file but it's very slow. I want to do it for all 500 files and concatenate to one dataframe:

```
DB_2017 = pd.read_csv("C:/folder/2018.dat",sep=",", header =None).iloc[: 0,4,5,6]

DB_2017.columns =["date","Code","Cur",Price]

DB_2017['Code'] =DB_2017['Code'].map(lambdax:x.lstrip('@').rstrip('@'))

DB_2017['Cur'] =DB_2017['Cur'].map(lambdax:x.lstrip('@').rstrip('@'))

DB_2017['date'] =DB_2017['date'].apply(lambdax:pd.timestamp(str(x)[:10)

DB_2017['Price'] =pd.to_numeric(DB_2017.Price.replace(',',';')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Have you read the pandas docs? You can specify the column names directly in `pandas.read_csv()`. You don’t need a map and a lambda to strip the characters from the column.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
def clean_up(df):
    df = df.iloc[:,[0,4,5,6]]
    df.columns = ["date","Code","Cur","Price"]
    df['Code'] = df['Code'].map(lambda x:x.lstrip('@').rstrip('@'))
    df['Cur'] = df['Cur'].map(lambda x:x.lstrip('@').rstrip('@'))
    df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x:pd.timestamp(str(x)[:10]))
    df['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price'].replace(',',';'), errors='coerce')
    return df

from pathlib import Path

file_path = Path("your_files_path/")

df = pd.concat([clean_up(pd.read_csv(i)) for  i in file_path.iterdir()])
```

In case, your path/folder contains files other than `.csv`, you can filter csv files using:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(i) for  i in file_path.glob('**/*.csv')])
```

To read `.dat` files, I think you can do:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_fwf(i) for  i in file_path.glob('**/*.dat')])
```

To read `.dat` files (a small sample), I think you can do:

```
n = 5
df = pd.concat([pd.read_fwf(i) for  i in file_path.glob('**/*.dat')[:n])
```

Comment: check the edit please, looks like I missed that part.

Comment: how many files do you have ? check the edit, may be something is wrong with file format. try reading first n files and see if it goes well

Comment: I have 50 files ans each files contain 56 MO...so very huge...the code still running as we speak

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up a generalized method that reads a csv and performs needed data cleaning. Then, loop through a directory of files to build list of data frames for concatenation. Be sure to use all needed arguments of `read_csv` including defaults:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

def proc_df(csv_file)
  DB = pd.read_csv(csv_file, header = None, sep=";",
                   names = ["date", "Code", "Cur", "Price"], 
                   usecols = [0,4,5,6])

  DB['Code'] = DB['Code'].str.lstrip('@').str.rstrip('@')
  DB['Cur'] = DB['Cur'].str.lstrip('@').str.rstrip('@')
  DB['date'] = pd.timestamp(DB['date'].str([:10]))
  DB['Price'] = pd.to_numeric(DB['Price'].replace(',',';')

  return DB

path = "C:/directory/to/data"

df_list = [proc_df(os.path.join(path, f)) for f in os.listdir(path)]

final_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index = True)
```

Comment: here is the error I got " Series' object has no attribute 'rstrip'"

Comment: The big issue I'm facing here is the timing and memory...as each files contain 55 MO and I have 100 files..

Comment: What is slow to you? 5 mins. or 50 mins.? Please comment out each line of function after `read_csv` but not `return` to check the slowest line. 100 files is not too many. What is MO?

Comment: Ah Sorry I meant to say 50 Mega Octet..after 3 hours I manage to CSV files